# Merging Branch in TortoiseSVN with history

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am working in a simple repository, with a truck and one branch. No change s have been made to the trunk since the branch, and a number of commits have been made on the branch. How do I merge the branch back into the trunk so that I get the full history included changes while it was in the branch in one history?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Subversion, one merges whole ranges into a single commit, like a squash merge in git:

```
svn merge -r[REVISION1]:[REVISION2] svn://[REPO-URL]/[BRANCH] [TRUNK-DIR]
```

Since Subversion 1.5, the information about the individual original commits is retained in the `svn:mergeinfo` property. In TortoiseSVN, you can find these under the menu item "Properties". On the command line, you can query that information as follows:

```
svn propget "svn:mergeinfo" [PATH]
```

If you really want to have a single merge commit per original commit, you need to do these yourself - which I imagine to be quite painful, especially with TortoiseSVN.

Alternatively, you can use a script to do the commits for you. Since you're using TortoiseSVN, I'm sure you're using Windows, so I whipped up a quick batch file to do the job. It will loop through a range of revisions, check if the source branch in fact has that revision, and if so, it will first merge it, and then commit it with a copy of the original commit message. `[REVISION1]` will be the first commit of the source branch and `[REVISION2]` will be the last commit of the source branch.

As it is and to keep things safe, this script only modifies your working copy (WC) by doing the `svn merge`s, but it does not do the `svn commit`s. So first, checkout the target branch (the trunk, in your case) into a fresh WC and inspect if this script runs as expected - i.e. if only the relevant revisions are merged into the WC. If so, checkout the target branch again into another fresh WC, and remove the last `REM` in the script to activate committing.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192099/1529709
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
SET BRANCH=svn://[REPO-URL]/[BRANCH]

FOR /L %%G IN ([REVISION1],1,[REVISION2]) DO (
    REM check if log is empty and only merge if not
    svn log -c %%G %BRANCH% > tmp-log.txt
    FINDSTR /V "\-----------" tmp-log.txt > NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ( 
        ECHO Merging revision %%G
        ECHO merge commit from %BRANCH% > tmp-commit.txt && ECHO. >> tmp-commit.txt
        TYPE tmp-log.txt >> tmp-commit.txt
        svn merge -c %%G %BRANCH% .

        REM *** check results first before you activate committing! ***
        REM svn commit -F tmp-commit.txt

    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Skipping revision %%G
    )
)
IF EXIST tmp-commit.txt DEL tmp-commit.txt
IF EXIST tmp-log.txt DEL tmp-log.txt
```

*Disclaimer: This script was inspired by this [variant for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192099/1529709) (which doesn't check for empty revisions)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this batch. Works perfect for me! I have a small addition to it:
I put svn update after the svn commit line. Like this:

```
svn commit -F tmp-commit.txt
svn update
```

otherwise on every next commit SVN would return you a message "Please, update your WC as you are trying to commit into a WC of not latest revision"